# Rails: Converting URL strings to params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know Rails does this for you, but I have a need to do this myself for examples. Is there a simple, non-private method available that takes a string and returns the hash of params exactly as Rails does for controllers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way after a more intense Google search.

To convert url string to params:

```
hash = CGI::parse(some_string)
```

And (as bonus) from hash back to url string:

```
some_string = hash.to_query
```

Thanks to: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/69428

Comment: that bonus helped me

Answer (score 15):

Using Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(some_string) will give you better results since CGI will convert all the values to arrays.

Comment: +1. `CGI::parse` also fails to correctly parse actual array parameters; _e.g.,_ for `foo[]=1&foo[]=2`, `CGI::parse` gives `{ 'foo[]' => ['1', '2'] }` whereas `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query` gives `{ 'foo' => ['1', '2'] }`.

Answer (score -1):

In model you can write a query like

```
def to_param
  "-#{self.first_name}" +"-"+ "#{self.last_name}"
end
```

More info

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

It will generate a url like http://ul.com/12-Ravin-Drope

More firendly url you can consult

https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732